# Variation of parameters: $y''-y'-2y=4e^{-t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use Variation of parameters to solve the second order linear equation: $$y''-y'-2y=4e^{-t}$$
any tips/solution? thanks :)

Comment: Do you know the general setup for variation of parameters? Can you solve the associated homogeneous equation?

Comment: yeah I can solve the homogenious equation: y=c1e^2x+c2e^-x I think I know how to solve with variation of parameters, so i tried and failed, and looked at my notes couldnt tell if I did something wrong so I ragequit, sometimes I wonder if im even using the correct formula..

Comment: @Amzoti hmm im not sure I have never seen this method on a equation of that form before

Comment: well it certainly looks like the formula I used, but idk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need the two indepedent solutions to the homogoneous equation $y''-y'-2y=0$.  Once you find that, you then compute the solution to the inhomogeneous problem using the variation of parameter formula
$$y_{p}(t)=v_{1}y_{1}(t)+v_{2}y_{2}(t),$$
where $y_{1},y_{2}$ are the independent solutions mentioned above and
$$v_{1}=-\int\frac{y_{2}(t)g(t)}{W(t)}\;dt$$
and
$$v_{2}=\int\frac{y_{1}(t)g(t)}{W(t)}\;dt.$$

Here $W(t)=y_{1}y_{2}'-y_{1}'y_{2},$ the "Wronskian" of the system, and $g(t)=4e^{-t}$, the "forcing" function of the system.

It would be more helpful if you presented your work in your question so that we can elaborate wherever it is you're having difficulty.

---

Sigh...you really ought to have done this on your own.

With $y_{1}(t)=e^{-t}$ and $y_{2}(t)=e^{2t}$ we get
$$v_{1}=-\frac{4}{3}\int e^{-t}e^{2t}e^{-t}\;dt=-\frac{4}{3}t$$
and
$$v_{2}=\frac{4}{3}\int e^{-t}e^{-t}e^{-t}\;dt=-\frac{4}{9}e^{-3t}.$$

According to our formula for $y_{p}$ then,
$$y_{p}(t)=-\frac{4}{3}te^{-t}-\frac{4}{9}e^{-t}.$$

Since $-\frac{4}{9}e^{-t}$ is already part of the homogeneous solution, we omit it from $y_{p}$, or otherwise absorb it into $c_{1}y_{1}(t)$ as $c_{1}$ is arbitrary.  The final solution incorporating $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ is then
$$y(t)=c_{1}e^{-t}+c_{2}e^{2t}-\frac{4}{3}te^{-t}.$$

Comment: is the wronskian in this question -3e^x?

Comment: $W[e^{-t},e^{2t}](t)=2e^{-t}e^{2t}-(-e^{-t}e^{2t})=2e^{t}+e^{t}=3e^{t}$.

Comment: well. W[e^2x e^-x] and then we have the derivative W[2e^2x -e^-x]
2e^2x * -e^-x and - (2e^2x *e^x) = -e^x -2e^x = -3e^x

Comment: Your answer is fine.  It depends on what you take to be $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$; permuting them in the definition of $W$ will only change the sign, since $W$ is a determinant.  But once you decide on your labeling, you must be consistant with the definitions for $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ (see the derivation of $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ in your text book).

Comment: ahh ok cool, so with your method I have y2 = e^-x and y1=e^2x?

Comment: NOPE i still cant do it, not even with that formula LOl.. idk what im doing wrong :(

Comment: Yes.  And just proclaiming you can't do it doesn't help us to help you.  I don't understand what's so difficult here; you're just computing integrals at this point, something you should have had lots of practice in before taking your current ODE course.

Comment: For example, $v_{1}$ (with my convention) is $-\int\frac{e^{2t}4e^{-t}}{3e^{t}}\;dt=-\frac{4}{3}\int\;dt=\frac{4}{3}t$.

Comment: ok an what is v_2? cuz the complete solution to this should be: Y(t)=-4/3te^-t

Comment: Well isn't that the question of the day; have you even attempted to compute it on your own?!

Comment: yeah and I have, and I cant get it to that solution thing :)

Comment: v2 should be -e^-t shouldnt it? atleast according to the solution in this book, im not sure if its right tho. and now way im managing to take the integral of e^-t in v2 :(

Comment: See extended answer above.